# GraphQL query structure

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

I'm learning GraphQL and am working with Apollo (client and server) I still have some confusion with the structure of GraphQL queries.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to merge the lines labeled `#1` and `#2` together? As the lines are so similar it almost feels redundant to have both.
2. If it is possible, is it advisable?
3. If not, what is the benefit of having a query structured in this way?

```
const AddUserQuery = gql`
  /*#1*/mutation addUser($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $email: String!) {
    /*#2*/addUser(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email) {
      id,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email
    }
  }`;
...
const [addUser, {data}] = useMutation(AddUserQuery);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Basically `#1` is you, telling Apollo you want a mutation, it's up to you if you name it or not, then, in `#2`, you're telling Apollo, which mutation you want to use.